# Changing text input size with Zurb Foundation (Rails 4.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I attempted the following:

```
<%= f.text_field :text, :style => "font-size:40px"%>
```

This increases the font size, but not the input box itself as it usually would without foundation. Is there a way to do this from within foundation without changing the global default?

I want this only for one input field.

[image]

Comment: I am using Foundation 4 in one of my Rails 4 projects, and cannot reproduce this behaviour. Setting larger font (as you did) automatically enlarges the text input.

Comment: Here is a screenshot: oi62.tinypic.com/1552jia.jpg

Comment: Can you paste the resulting HTML?

Comment: <input id="response_text" name="response[text]" style="font-size:40px" type="text" />

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, I think you can set size.

Try

```
<%= f.text_field :text, :size => 20 %>
```

Comment: No effect. font and textbox stay at the default 14

Answer (score 0):

Set width with column class and height with 'size' per below:

```
    <div>
      <%= f.text_area :content, size: 'x5' %>
    </div>
```